# Residues and blow ups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

On a 2-dimensional complex manifold consider two functions which are meromorphic with singularities along two divisors which meet at a point. There is a residue which is a 2-form at the point of intersection.

We could also blow up the point of intersection to $\mathbb{CP}^1$. What connection is there between the blow up and the meromorphic functions? In particular, is there a construction on the blow up given by the meromorphic functions (e.g. a construction of sections of a line bundle??) which naturally gives the residue (as a 2-form)?

Apologies, I am not an algebraic geometer and am finding my way around this subject. I am looking at applications to integrable systems, and require a way to look at the residue as a purely point construction, rather than associated to the original divisors...